# How do I delete a record with same id present in two collections in monogo database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

I am having two collections in mongodb.I am unable to delete a record having same id present in two different collections.

```
userRouter.post('/deleteProject', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body._id);
  Collections.projectdetail.findOneAndRemove(
    { _id: req.body._id }, 
    {},
    function (error, resp) {
      if (error)
        return console.log("Error: " + error.message);
      return res.status(200).send(resp);
  })
  Collections.issuedetail.findOneAndRemove(
    { _id: req.body._id }ת
    {},
    function (error, resp) {
      if (error)
        return console.log("Error: " + error.message);
      return res.status(200).send(resp);
  })
});
```

No errors

Comment: How it was possible to have same id in different collections?

Comment: In my project the client will create projects.For every project they will raise many number of issues.So for every project I generated one project id and stored in projects collection.And for every project issues are stored in issue details collection with the project id . So If I delete project from projects collection.The issues present in issues collection with this project id must be deleted in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you should call is findOneAndDelete: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/
check the documentation and try to handle the response properly

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.projectdetail.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.body._id },{ },
  function (error, resp) {
      if (error)
          return console.log("Error: " + error.message);
      else{
            Collections.issuedetail.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.body._id }, { },
            function (error, resp) {
                if (error)
                    return console.log("Error: " + error.message);
                return res.status(200).send(resp);
          })
      }
 });
```

Comment: It's working fine but deleting only one record in the second collection.I need to delete multiple records with same id.

Comment: Finally this worked for me....  for issuedetail collection deleteMany() query has worked.